# Root redirect to application with embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm migrating an existing Spring Boot project (war) to use embedded Tomcat (jar).

The old non-embedded Tomcat this was deployed into had 2 webapps:

1. `myapp`: which is my Spring Boot application
2. `ROOT`: which only contained an index.jsp that setup a redirect to `myapp`

Now that I'm migrating to embedded tomcat, I set the `server.servlet.context-path=/myapp` and I have everything working except the forwarding that the ROOT webapp was handling.

The behavior I'm looking for is if users browse to `http://<baseurl>/` it redirects them to `http://<baseurl>/myapp`

How should I handle this?

Comment: So, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

change it to `server.servlet.context-path=/myapp`
[Refered from](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties)

Comment: I had a typo in my original question. The question should have read server.servlet.context-path as Ravikumar suggests, not server.servlet.path as I originally had. Thanks for the call out. Same question though. How do I handle the redirect?

Comment: @MrQBerrt which spring boot version you are using!?

Comment: Did you tried this https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/change-application-root-context-path/

Comment: First, I'm using Spring-Boot 2. Second, that article describes how to change my context-path. I have the context path the way I'd like to leave it. What I'm asking is how to setup a forward from outside of the context-path into the context-path.